# Essential spectrum of operators whose resolvent difference is compact

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, compact-operators

Suppose that $T,S$ are densely defined, closed (unbounded) operators on a separable Hilbert space such that there exists $z \in \mathbb C$ in the intersection of resolvent sets of $T$ and $S$ for which $(T-z)^{-1}-(S-z)^{-1}$ is compact. Does it follow that $T$ and $S$ have the same essential spectrum?

Remark: in the application I have in mind $S-T$ is unbounded and domains of $S$ and $T$ are not necessarily equal.

Comment: You're right: my deleted answer only works for bounded operators.

Comment: Thoughts (based on my deleted answer): without loss of generality, we can take $z = 0$ and suppose that $T^{-1} - S^{-1}$ is compact. If $S$ and $T$ are a counterexample to the statement, then it must hold that $S - T$ fails to be compact (despite the compactness of $T^{-1} - S^{-1}$).

Comment: I'd try MO ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been shown in J. J. Buoni ''An Essential Spectra Mapping Theorem'', J. Math. Anal. Appl. 56 (1976) that
$$ \sigma_{\mathrm{ess}}(S) = \{ z' \in \mathbb C \, | \, \exists w \in \sigma_{\mathrm{ess}}((S-z)^{-1}) \ \  (z'-z)w =1 \}. $$
The same is true with $T$ replaced by $S$. Since $(T-z)^{-1}-(S-z)^{-1}$ is compact, $\sigma_{\mathrm{ess}}((T-z)^{-1}) = \sigma_{\mathrm{ess}}((S-z)^{-1})$, so the above formula entails $\sigma_{\mathrm{ess}}(S) = \sigma_{\mathrm{ess}}(T)$.